# express-session closing in a minute and displaying err

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, hosting

After deployment of my app on hosting service i run into problem of this message displaying after 3-5 get requests:
Incomplete response received from application
after that more of those errors popped out and session reseted
code of app.js:

````
// native node and express
const path = require('path');
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const session = require('express-session');
const env = require('dotenv');
env.config();
const ruteing = require('./routeing/main');
const messageRouteing = require('./routeing/messages');
const authenticationRoutering = require('./routeing/authentication');

//set extenction settings
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('render engine', 'pug');
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false}));
app.use(session({
  secret: process.env.SECRET,
  resave: false,
  saveUninitialized: false
}));

// create access routing from exported rutering
app.use('/', ruteing);
app.use('/m', messageRouteing);
app.use('/a', authenticationRoutering);
app.get('*', (req, res) => {
  res.render('404.pug');
});
app.listen(3000, () => console.log('i do not even know what am i doing'))```

My hosting is mydevil
````

Comment: Does the same code works for you locally? Can you post more details of the error?

Comment: @ronnyfm Locally it works just fine. After migrating to hosting it doesen't work. You log in it's fine do more stuff it's ok but then error displays and is not put in logs

Comment: You need to set maxAge: new Date(Date.now() + 31536000000), in app.use(session({})). Also check here for more info https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-session